# In a Django test, how to load a sample JSON file?

Tags: django, api, unit-testing, testing, fixtures

I'm writing tests for a Django app that fetches and parses JSON data from an API. I want to test the parsing by giving the method a known, sample JSON file. Two questions:

1. Where would it be best to put this? It's not quite a fixture, so I'm not sure if putting it in my app's `fixtures/` directory will be confusing.
2. I know I can load the file using `open()` but how should I specify the correct filepath in a way that will be robust?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but one time I got tired of mocking requests, so wrote a thing that would spin up a server and return json fixtures: https://github.com/KPBS/py3-pmp-wrapper/blob/master/test/server.py. You can see how they're called in any of the actual tests.  Maybe a crazy solution? I've kinda always wondered. (Also should mention: it was written in Python3.)

Comment: PS. It sounds like a fixture to me.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! Yes, maybe they are fixtures. I just hadn't seen anyone put these in `fixtures/` and wondered if it's the kind of thing about which more experienced folk would say "Well, obviously those shouldn't go there, they should go here…"